# creating binary max Heap not working fine in Js

Tags: javascript, data-structures, binary-tree

I am creating a max heap binary tree where I have to insert a list of items [3, 4, 31, 6] and wanted output like [ 31, 6, 4, 3] ,here I have wrote the function but its gave the undefined value ,how to make it correct or any suggestion ,code is given below

```
function binaryHeap(element) {
    let values = []; 
    values.push(element); 
    let index = values.length - 1; 
    const current = values[index];
    while (index > 0) {
      let parentIndex = Math.floor((index - 1) / 2); 
      let parent = values[parentIndex];
      if (parent <= current) {
        values[parentIndex] = current;
        values[index] = parent;
        index = parentIndex;
      } else break;
    }
  }
  console.log(binaryHeap([3, 4, 31, 6]));
```

Comment: Your function doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: what tree are you building? why do you want to get largest values first?

Comment: no I just want to create a binary Heap function that will return max heap like if I call that function binaryHeap([3, 4, 31, 6]) will return [ 31, 6, 4, 3] like that perform the max heap tree functionality

Comment: Can you give some other examples of input and expected output? The example you gave seems like you just want a sorted array.

Comment: i had a js maxheap written so i created a gist https://gist.github.com/cmgchess/731b887c7ac2799d6f49b42aebd31213#file-maxheap-js